# Bookmark Searches with Dash?

Tags: unity-dash, search, bookmarks

Is there any way to configure Dash to search/access Firefox bookmarks, too? Seems like it would completely replace Gnome Do for most things if it could do this one thing. Gnome Do keeps causing errors with the login keyring, so I've given up on using it, but I miss being able to access my favorite bookmarks with just a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 2):

Such a tool happens to already exists: the [Bookmarks Lens](https://launchpad.net/bookmarks-lens).

You can install it by following these directions:

1. Run the following command in a terminal:

   > `sudo apt-get install libunity-dev libsqlite3-dev intltool`
2. Download [this](http://launchpad.net/bookmarks-lens/0.1/0.0.6/+download/bookmarks-lens-0.0.6.tar.gz) file.
3. Extracting the contents of the archive somewhere (say `~/bm-lens`).
4. Open a terminal and navigating to the directory you extracted the files to.
5. Run the following command:

   > `./configure ; make`
6. Once that completes, run:

   > `sudo make install`
7. Restart Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Funny you should ask!  [This](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/unity-bookmark-lens-for-ubuntu-1110.html) was posted just a few days ago in [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org) and seems to be what you're seeking. According to the page, you can either get it at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/bookmarks-lens) or from a repository created for it: the following is all a quote from WebUpd8:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bookmarks-lens
```

Once installed, run the following command:

```
setsid unity
```

And the new Unity Bookmarks Lens should show up in Dash. If the new lens doesn't display any bookmarks, try restarting your computer.